# Removing empty nodes from an XML document created by a .builder template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, builder, tilt

I have a problem like [What's the cleanest way to ignore empty nodes with Nokogiri::XML::Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391976/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-ignore-empty-nodes-with-nokogirixmlbuilder) , except that my XML document is generated by a .builder template file using the builder gem.

I'm generating an XML document using the [builder gem](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder) (and [tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt)) and I want to get rid of empty nodes.

The answer [suggesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5403859/38765) just iterating through each attribute and deciding whether to serialise each attribute or not isn't very suitable to my application, because there's quite a lot of logic involved in building the XML document.

The answer [suggesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391976/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-ignore-empty-nodes-with-nokogirixmlbuilder) the use of `Nokogiri::XML::Node#traverse` doesn't look bad, but I suspect this approach isn't supported by the builder gem. The documentation for builder [says](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/builder/)

> An `Builder::XmlTree` class to generate XML tree (i.e. DOM-like)
>   structures is also planned, but not yet implemented. Also, the events
>   builder is currently lagging the markup builder in features.

(I'm not sure if the quoted section is equivalent to `Nokogiri::XML::Node#traverse`, but it does at the least suggest that there's some functionality not available in Builder)

Also, searching for some sort of [remove](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=remove&type=) method doesn't get a match in the git repository.

The builder gem, as of 2017, is largely abandoned. The master branch last had a commit in June 2013, and there's only been a [handful of commits in forks](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder/network) since then. Tilt's mention of maintenance only refers to the maintenance of integration between tilt and builder.

Are there any gems that support the `.builder` format other than the builder gem?

Do I have any alternatives other than adding a lot of `if title` or `if feed` conditionals to the `.builder` file, or once I've created the XML, feeding it through an unrelated XML parser?

Comment: Related meta question about the builder tag: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353757/the-builder-needs-to-construct-two-tags

Comment: Just noting that it looks like the tenderlove branch is being made the official branch for `builder` [(source)](https://github.com/jimweirich/builder/issues/56)...still only 12 commits ahead of the repo you have linked, but looks like that's why the bulk of the work will be done in the future